# Is there a way to create micro fiber from nodes?

Tags: texturing, materials

I want to create a suede micro fiber material with tiny hairs like shown in the images below, is this possible with a simple bump map?

[image]

So far, this is what I could achieve (it looks more like a hard plastic):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Velvet BSDF material node? Might need to be combined with Mix Node with what you have already.

Comment: I've not been able to fully replicate the requested material, but I do know that some IOR-based mixing might be needed as well. The fresnel effect creates the light edges; a greater angle of incidence = lower saturation, higher value. https://i.stack.imgur.com/urcug.jpg (note that 1.25 IOR is fairly high; try experimenting with values between 1 and 1.1)

Comment: @rob Velvet node doesn't give that great results.

Comment: @asoftbird No problem. The texture still looks like plastic. I will try to come up with a solution